# Running swift package plugin in Terminal end with "Platform Path" errors

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm having an issue making a Swift package plugin work.
At one point, I'm trying to list all available plugins linked to the package using the following command:

```bash
swift package plugin --list
```

After running the command, I get the following errors:

```bash
error: terminated(1): /usr/bin/xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-platform-path output:
    xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'PlatformPath' from command line tools installation
    xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'PlatformPath' in SDK '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
```

I don't seem to figure out what is going on.
I have Xcode 14.3 installed.

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Running `xcode-select -p` reveals the current path:

```
% xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

For swift on terminal to work properly, change the path using:

```
% sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

And the command you were trying to run should work.

If for some reason you need to restore the original path, use:

```
% sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```